# what are the steps to implement neo4j, gremlin for codeigniter user

Tags: codeigniter, neo4j, database-migration, gremlin

I need to migrate from RDBMS to GRAPH and decide to implement neo4j with gremlin. But I only have PHP as a server side language. What are the steps to implement neo4j (and gremlin?) in codeigniter environment. May be this question is too general but I'm sure many people have the same problem like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but since Cypher http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/cypher-query-lang.html is the native Neo4j language and very SQL-like, that might be an easier option?

Comment: Reading on progress ... Thanks and Regard for Peter.
Any suggestions still open.

Answer (score 1):

In general, (not sure about PHP frameworks), you will want to do the following process.

1. For all your "objects tables," loop through the rows and create a respective vertex. For the columns of those rows (e.g. id, name, age), add them as properties of the vertex. For instance, if you have a Person-table, then **SELECT * FROM Person**. Each row is a vertex with properties.
2. For all your "relational tables" (or that which is relational via join), loop through the rows and link your vertices. For instance **SELECT personId, companyID FROM WorksFor**. Each row is an edge that links a person vertex with a company vertex.

Adding vertices/edges via Gremlin is simple. The complicated aspect of your process, is the workflow you go through to create your mapping.

https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Updating-a-Graph

Finally, be sure to be smart about transaction handling so you don't blow your heap. You will want to commit your transaction every so often to have the data persisted to disk.

Comment: Thankyou for all. Sorry too late to response.I have to bedrest in hospital for a while. A coronary heart attack.

Answer (score 0):

implementing this library should work in codeigniter too:
https://github.com/jadell/Neo4jPHP/wiki